# RecyclerView adapter's item click not working according to need

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and I have 9 items inside it and when I click on one item it should get selected, but when I select another item it should get selected and the other item should get un-selcted, automatically.

What am I doing wrong, any help is appreciable thanks.

Here is my Adapter's code

```
class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.DataViewHolder> {

    private final int mItemCount;
    List<ServicesMenuModel> mServiceList;
    SparseBooleanArray mArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    int pos;

    ItemAdapter(int itemCount, List<ServicesMenuModel> mServiceList) {
        mItemCount = itemCount;
        this.mServiceList = mServiceList;
    }

    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list_dialog_item6, parent, false);
        return new DataViewHolder(v);
    }

    public void changeAt(int position, DataViewHolder holder) {
        mArray.delete(position);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
        holder.mServiceText.setSelected(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mServiceText.setText(mServiceList.get(position).getMenuText());

        holder.mServiceText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.mServiceText.setSelected(mArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition(), false));
                pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();

                //When same item is clicked
                if (mArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition(), false)) {
                    mArray.delete(pos);
                    holder.mServiceText.setSelected(false);
                } else
                //When new item is selected
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < mServiceList.size(); i++) {
                        changeAt(i, holder);//checking to remove other items
                    }
                    mArray.put(holder.getAdapterPosition(), true);
                    holder.mServiceText.setSelected(true);
                }

                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onItemClicked(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mServiceList.size();
    }

    class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mServiceText;

        DataViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mServiceText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the BottomSheetDialogFragment listener, we can ignore it for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your requirement is to select one item at a time. I would recommend the following method rather than keeping an array of boolean.

Declare a variable to hold last selected item's index in the adapter class.

```
int mLastSelectedIndex = -1;
```

Inside the `ViewHolder` define the onClick method like this.

```
void setUpOnClick(final int position) {    
    boolean selection = position == mLastSelectedPosition;
    mServiceText.setSelected(selection);

    mServiceText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int tempOldIndex = mLastSelectedPosition;
            mLastSelectedPosition = position;

            if (tempOldIndex >= 0) {
                notifyItemChanged(tempOldIndex);
            }
            notifyItemChanged(position);

            // your regular code
        }
    }
}
```

at last, call it inside onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DataViewHolder holder, int position {
    holder.setUpOnClick(position);

    // your regular code
}
```

Comment: For single item selection it is working but what to do if I click on the same item, I need to make the view gone

Comment: @RakshitNawani may be you can try like this.

    boolean selection = position == mLastSelectedPosition;
    boolean isSelected = mServiceText.isSelected();
    mServiceText.setSelected(selection && !isSelected);

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly a wrong way to do this:

```
holder.mServiceText.setSelected(false);
```

Because this `ViewHolder` is being reused for another items of your `RecyclerView` too, which will make other items of `RecyclerView` to be selected as you scroll up and forth.

Instead, declare a field in `ViewHolder`, e.g. `boolean isSelected` and mutate that field:

```
holder.isSelected = true;
```

Then in `onBindViewHolder()` show the content depending on that boolean:

```
if (holder.isSelected) {
    // display selected content
} else {
    // display unselected content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test but it would work. Main key is using list instance.

Hope it's helpful. Also if your listener make some UI change I would put notify~ function to the place where your adapter is being used.

```
package net.deali.ssmarket.view;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import net.deali.ssmarket.R;

import java.util.List;

import static android.media.CamcorderProfile.get;

/**
 * Created by soochun on 2017-04-24.
 */

class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.DataViewHolder> {

    List<ServicesMenuModel> mServiceList;

    ItemAdapter(int itemCount, List<ServicesMenuModel> mServiceList) {
        this.mServiceList = mServiceList;
    }

    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list_dialog_item6, parent, false);
        return new DataViewHolder(v);
    }

    public void changeAt(int position, DataViewHolder holder) {
        notifyItemChanged(position);
        holder.mServiceText.setSelected(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ServicesMenuModel item = mServiceList.get(position);
        holder.mServiceText.setText(item.getMenuText());
        holder.mServiceText.setSelected(item.isSelected());
        holder.mServiceText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 boolean setValue = !item.isSelected();
                 item.setSelected(setValue);
                 notifyItemChanged(position, item);

               //if even one item is selected, should make other items make unselected.
                if (setValue) {
                    int i = 0;
                    for (ServicesMenuModel servicesMenuModel : mServiceList) {
                        if (i != position) {
                            servicesMenuModel.setSelected(false);
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged(); //if recyclerView move top postion try to use notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mServiceList.size());
                }

                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onItemClicked(position);
                    dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mServiceList.size();
    }

    class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mServiceText;

        DataViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mServiceText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }

    class ServicesMenuModel {
        String menuText;
        boolean isSelected;

        public String getMenuText() {
            return menuText;
        }

        public void setMenuText(String menuText) {
            this.menuText = menuText;
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return isSelected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            isSelected = selected;
        }
    }
}
```